# How to databind a control in WebForms like you do in ASP MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, web, webforms

I'm doing some web forms development after having developed using ASP MVC for a long time. Is there a way to databind the controls the way you do it in MVC? In MVC I'd have a model class and then bind the property to a control like this.

```
@model MyClass

@Html.TextboxFor(x => Model.Name)
```

However, in MVC when I use an  it looks like I have to do the binding manually on the codebehind. Is there a way of declaring a model class for the page and then do something like this?

```
<asp:TextBox Text="<% Model.Name %>" />
```

Comment: I think this post will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5264852/can-we-use-razor-syntax-in-asp-net-webforms-aspx-pages

Comment: Reading another post I can use <%# %> and then use the DataBind action of the Page in the codebehind to bind the value of a public property to that control.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595851/set-visible-property-with-server-tag-in-framework-3-5

Comment: OK, I think I see what you are trying to do. Maybe even simpler than `<%# %>` could be to just declare your model class as `protected` in the code-behind.  Protected variables are accessible from client code using `<%= %>` notation.